# Ruby on Rails select2 submit doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-select2, select2-rails

```
  https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage
```

I want to search for a Post title like the first example in the link above.

Code:

```
<!-- search -->
      <div class="card my-auto">
        <%= form_with url: posts_path, method: :get, local: :true do |f| %>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Search for a Post title.</p>
            <%= f.collection_select(:post_id, Post.all, :id, :title, {include_blank: 'Post titles'}, {class:'selectbooktitle form-control'}) %>
            <hr>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <%= f.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-success'%>

                </span>
        <% end %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the Request from my server when clicking on Submit.

```
Started GET "/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&post_id=16&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-09 14:18:51 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "post_id"=>"16", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY created_at DESC
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 55.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Leads to this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&post_id=20&commit=Search
```

it should lead to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/20
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Ok. what did you try? Where you got stuck?

Comment: I tried implementing the f.collection_select line that I posted - says NoMethod error collection_select

Comment: That's because `f` is `nil`. *#form_tag* doesn't pass any params to it's block. You'll have to use *#form_with* instead (set `local: true` if you want to keep the same behaviour). http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: @JohanWentholt Yes! Ive got my form working now, but the only problem I still have is whenever I try to submit my form, it won't actually switch the page to the chosen-search-object.. It changes the URL to http://localhost:3000/posts?utf8=%E2%9C%93&post_id=16&commit=Search but wont actually change the page.

Comment: If you want the exact same form as in you example you have to set the following: `form_with url: posts_path, method: :get, local: :true`. Do you have those options set? If yes, what request do you receive on the server?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my Question with my current code. I did that already with the link you sent. 

Whenever I want to open a Post-Show-Page via the Submit button, it just changes the URL but won't actually change the page as I mentioned earlier. I will update my Question with the full request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails framework is not wrong for sending you to that URL, since you set the *form_with* `:url` option to `posts_path`. This is equal to `/posts`.

What you are trying to do is change the form action based on the select content. For this you'll need JavaScript to change the form action on the fly.

Here is a simplified example:

**app/views/some_directory/some_file.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with url: posts_path, method: :get, local: true do |form| %>
  <% options = {include_blank: 'Post titles'} %>
  <% html_options = {
     class: 'selectbooktitle form-control', 
     'data-change-form-action-with-value': true,
  } %>

  <%= form.collection_select :post_path, Post.all, method(:post_path), :title, options, html_options %>
  <%= form.submit 'Search', class: 'btn btn-outline-success'%>
<% end %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/some_file.coffee**

```
initChangeFormActionWithValue = (selectElement) ->
  selectElement       = $(selectElement)
  closestAncestorForm = selectElement.closest('form')

  selectElement.on 'change', ->
    closestAncestorForm.attr 'action', selectElement.val()

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('select[data-change-form-action-with-value="true"]')
    .each -> initChangeFormActionWithValue(this)
```

Now when changing the select value the form is updated with the value of the selected option (which contains the post path). And when you submit your request you'll request `GET /posts/:id`.

> **Note:** This is a simplified solution. Which requests `GET /posts/:id` of the selected post. However the values of the form are also submitted. You can leave them unhandled, but should at least know that their there. So you are not surprised when you see the *post_path* or *submit* params in the show.
>
> Furthermore if you don't change the select at all when pressing submit you currently just request `GET /posts`. And if you change to select value to a post and back to `'Post titles'` (the blank value), the action is cleared. Which means you get the current URL.

---

Alternatively you can go with your current solution. Than in your *PostsController#index* redirect to *PostsController#show* if `params[:post_id]` is present.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    return redirect_to post_path(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]

    # other index code
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer! I see the problem that I was going through now and was able to fix it.

Basically, your JavaScript example looks reasonable to me- but I still went with your alternative solution because it just works with the way I tried it.
You have my upvote here and the best answer as well for sure!